# Convert format, discard audio, resize frames and apply watermark in ffmpeg at once

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to achieve what I asked in title, but FFMpeg produces a 0 byte size file.

Here is the code [not working]:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -codec copy -i watermark.png -filter_complex '[0:v] scale=1920:-1,setsar=1:1; [1:v] overlay=0:0' output.mp4
```

if possible I want to do the whole thing in just 1 command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i watermark.png \
  -filter_complex '[0:v] scale=1920:-1,setsar=1:1[v]; [v][1:v]overlay=0:0[out]' \
  -map [out] -an output.mp4
```

- `-codec copy` - No can do if you want to apply filter
- `-an` disables audio
- Filtergraph: you were missing label `[v]` to connect to the chains.